# Is there a limit to the queue size in an IntentService?

Tags: android, intentservice

I'm not likely to hit any roof that may exist, but it is possible that i might send a lot of intents to an IntentService.

I was curious to find out if there is an upper limit to how many Intents you can send to a IntentService? Is there a size limit to the queue? I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr No.**

From android source (API 19):

It looks like the `IntentService` just uses a regular `Looper` and `Handler` tied to a thread.

When you call start on the intent service with a new intent, it just sends the intent to the handler as a message.

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    msg.obj = intent;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

The handler:

```
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        onHandleIntent((Intent)msg.obj);
        stopSelf(msg.arg1);
    }
}
```

The `Looper` that the `Handler` uses has a `MessageQueue` that does not have a maximum number of items that can be added to it.

Comment: Make sure to read Terek's answer also.  you are always system resource limited.  Would be interesting to know what that looks like though.  What is the queue structure behind Handler?  maybe its that limit.

Answer (score 1):

In theory there is no limit, but the app might run out of memory depending on the size of the data being passed in.